# How to contain variables within function when function is triggered multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a gresemonkey script.(client-side triggerd javascript)

Because you can't browse multiple pages with greasemonkey, It appends a bunch of iFrames to the DOM and every time an iFrame is opened, it shall perform a few thins to the content in that iframe:

```
$('.bolagsverket').load(function() {
    var orgnr = $(this).attr('id')
    var datablob = $(this).contents().find('.kungtext').text();
    console.log(datablob)
 });
```

When i log the datablob, it comes out with the value from the last iFrame every time, rather than the unique value of that iframe. Why?

Comment: Can you `alert(datablob)` instead? It might be possible that the console shows you the latest data. I had a similar issue while logging an object that I was retrieving asynchronously. More details: http://techblog.appnexus.com/2011/webkit-chrome-safari-console-log-bug/

Comment: I had the wrong idea all together, it turns out, the iframe opened contained the same page.